# Upgraded react native version

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, upgrade

After upgrading my react native version from 0.63.3 to latest version, I am getting the following errors:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:.
     Required by:
         project :
```

Following are the dependencies in my build.gradle file:

```
   dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Would anyone be able to explain this to me? It would be greatly appreciated if you could help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The github issue that @RamaProg suggested does provide some insight but it was in the context of building `react-native` from source. And i believe that issue was created before `0.68.1` was a stable public release.

Following the upgrade guide here: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.67.4&to=0.68.1

Suggests the following addititons to `settings.gradle`:

```
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')
if (settings.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && settings.newArchEnabled == "true") {
    include(":ReactAndroid")
    project(":ReactAndroid").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid')
}
```

And this change is what resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

I got this issue recently after upgrading to v68+.
It was fixed when I added `react-native-gradle-plugin` package manually.

`yarn add react-native-gradle-plugin`

This package was not included in upgrade helper.

Answer (score 2):

According to this RN issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33067

You issue might get fixed by going to your settings.gradle and replacing:

```
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native/packages/react-native-gradle-plugin')
```

with:

```
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native/packages/react-native-gradle-plugin') {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute(module("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")).using(project(":"))
    }
}
```

> The problem is that you're using an older revision of the repo, therefore the wiki is updated to use the latest main. Building from source from different revision is generally not supported (i.e. you're on your own) as there are those kinds of incompatibilities, and we can't provide instructions for all the possible RN versions/branches.